# How to look for a log entry in kibana without filtering out other ones?

Tags: filter, kibana, kibana-6

While analyzing logs, we sometimes need to look for logs just before or after a certain line.

I can't seem to find a way to search for anything without filtering out everything else.

For example I'm looking for an entry with `timestamp=12:34:55`, but I don't want to exactly find that, I want to look at the log entries around that one to get some context.

another example is that a customer says that they are getting weird values in logs whenever the line

`Select xyz mode to write file.txt`

So I need to go to every-time this occurs in the logs and look at the logs near this one.

Is there a way to do this in kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every log entry in kibana, when expanded, you can click on the `view surrounding documents` button, which shows you 5 log entries above and below the current one, and an option to increase the documents shown on wither side.